# String split into duplicate rows

Tags: r

Given the following sample dataset:

```
col1 <- c("X1","X2","X3|X4|X5","X6|X7")
col2 <- c("5","8","1","4")
dat <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

How can I split the `col1` by `|` and enter them as separate rows with duplicated `col2` values? Here's the dataframe that I'd like to end up with:

```
col1 col2
  X1    5
  X2    8
  X3    1
  X4    1
  X5    1
  X6    4
  X7    4
```

I need a solution that can accomodate multiple columns similar to `col2` that also need to be duplicated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! As you are new on SO, please take some time to read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [how to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is great that you have provide a [minimal, reproducible data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). However, it is also important that you show us what you have tried. I am sure many people out there (e.g. me) are much more willing to help if you share the code you have tried and explain where it went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You can try `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package: `library(splitstackshape); concat.split.multiple(dat, "col1", "|", "long")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just split the character string and then repeat the other columns based on the length.

```
y<-strsplit(as.character( dat[,1])  , "|", fixed=TRUE)
data.frame(col1= unlist(y), col2= rep(dat[,2], sapply(y, length)))
  col1 col2
1   X1    5
2   X2    8
3   X3    1
4   X4    1
5   X5    1
6   X6    4
7   X7    4
```

And if you need to repeat many columns except the first

```
data.frame(col1= unlist(y), dat[ rep(1:nrow(dat), sapply(y, length)) , -1 ] )
```

Comment: I would use `tidyr` now, try `separate_rows(dat, col1, sep="\\|")`